# costmap parameters - navigation stack

Tags: ros, dwa-local-planner, parameters, 2dcostmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

for me it's unclear what parameters **have to/can** be in common_costmap_params.yaml, local_costmap_params.yaml and global_costmap_params.yaml

This tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup doesn't really help me.
To start with I just want to use a hand-drawn static map.

Every yaml file i could find in github projects uses different parameters / is otherwise structured. I want to use it together with dwa_local_planner. Also the parameters here differ from project to project and it seems that the ROS Wiki doesn't cover every parameter possible.

At the moment I always get the message "dwa planner failed to produce path". To find the problem I think it would be good the be full aware of the possible parameters and their influence on the system.

I appreciate any help / possible guides.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279148/costmap-parameters---navigation-stack/) by [Mumie](https://answers.ros.org/users/31881/mumie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2018-01-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The total cost of a cell in a costmap is calculated from a [set of layers](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d?distro=lunar#Overview) that, together, define the whole costmap. The three most common layers and the associated documentation of all parameters are:

1. [Static Map Layer](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d/hydro/staticmap)
2. [Obstacle Map Layer](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d/hydro/obstacles)
3. [Inflation Layer](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d/hydro/inflation)

Nearly all the examples you have likely found on GitHub are using defining the parameters in their YAML files according to the documentation on the 3 previous links. Note that there is also an old, pre-Hydro way of defining costmap params that you may still find lurking on the internet, and there are a few additional layers that people have developed. This is all described at the end of the [costmap_2d page](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d?distro=lunar#Component_API).

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2018-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0